# GitLab cicd pipeline could not able to find to find node_modules

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, node-modules

I Have updated node version to 18.17.1 from that time my build getting
failed because gitlab pipeline not able to locate node_modules,
getting below error.

```
FAIL src/services/authentication/index.spec.js   ● Test suite failed
to run
    Configuration error:
    Could not locate module aws-amplify mapped as:
    /builds/project-name/repository-name/node_modules/aws-amplify.
    Please check your configuration for these entries:
    {
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/aws-amplify/": "/builds/project-name/repository-name/node_modules/aws-amplify"
      },
      "resolver": undefined
    }
      1 | /* eslint-disable camelcase */
    > 2 | import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';
        | ^
      3 | import queryString from 'query-string';
      4 | import { localStorageService, httpService, sessionStorageService } from '..';
      5 | import environment from '../../config/environment';
      at createNoMappedModuleFoundError (../../../node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:759:17)
      at Object.require (src/services/authentication/index.js:2:1)
      at Object.require (src/services/index.js:4:1)
      at Object.require (src/services/authentication/index.spec.js:1:1) PASS
src/redux/actions/session/action.spec.js FAIL
src/components/Home/index.spec.jsx

Pipeline-script: dev-build:   image:
public.ecr.aws/8734dndn/node:18.17.1   stage: dev-build   script:
    - sh prepareenv.sh dev
    - cp environment.common.js ./src/config/environment/environment.dev.js
    - npm run test
    - npm run build development   artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist
    expire_in: 1 week    only:
    - master
    - /^RELEASE.*$/
```